# No data collected when I extract info from a website using xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I'd need to extract information from a website. This website has information inside the following path:

```
<div class="accordion-block__question">
<div class="accordion-block__text">Server</div></div>
...
<div class="block__col"><b>Country</b></div>
```

Running

```
try: 
            # Country
            c=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'block__col') and contains(text(),'Country')]").get_attribute('textContent')
            country.append(c)   
except: 
            country.append("Error")
```

I create a df with all errors. I'd interest in all the fields (but for fixing this issue, just one would be great), included the Trustscore (number), but I don't know if it'd possible to get it. I'm using selenium, web driver on Chrome.
The website is https://www.scamadviser.com/check-website.

**CODE**

This is the entire code:

```
def scam(df):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    trust=[]
    country = [] 
    isp_country = [] 
        
    query=df['URL'].unique().tolist() 
    driver=webdriver.Chrome('mypath',chrome_options=chrome_options))
    
    for x in query:
        
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        response=driver.get('https://www.scamadviser.com/check-website/'+x)
        
        try: 
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
            # missing trustscore

            # Country
            c=driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'block__col') and contains(text(),'Country')]")).get_attribute('innerText')
            country.append(c)  

            # ISP country
        ic=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'block__col') and contains(text(),'ISP')]").get_attribute('innerText')
            isp_country.append(ic)
        
        except: 
            # missing trustscore
            country.append("Error")
            isp_country.append("Error")
            

    # Create dataframe
    dict = {'URL': query, 'Trustscore':trust, 'Country': country, 'ISP': isp_country} 
    df=pd.DataFrame(dict)

    driver.quit()
    
    return df
```

You can try for example with df['URL'] equal to

```
stackoverflow.com
gitHub.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `innerText` not `textContent`.

**Code :**

```
try: 
  # Country
  c = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'block__col') and contains(text(),'Country')]").get_attribute('innerText')
  print(c)
  country.append(c)   
except: 
   country.append("Error")
```

**Updated 1 :**

In case already used locator is correct.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'block__col') and contains(text(),'Country')]"))
```

or may be try with both the options with this xpath :-

```
//div[contains(@class,'block__col')]/b[text()='Country']
```

**Udpated 2 :**

try:
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
# missing trustscore

```
# Country
time.sleep(2)
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'block__col')]/b[text()='Country']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele)
country.append(ele.get_attribute('innerText'))

time.sleep(2)
# ISP country
ic = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'block__col')]/b[text()='ISP']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele)
isp_country.append(ic.get_attribute('innerText'))
```

**Udpate 3 :**

to get the `Company data`, `Country name`.

use this **xpath** :

```
//div[text()='Company data']/../following-sibling::div/descendant::b[text()='Country']/../following-sibling::div
```

also, make sure few things before using this xpath.

1. Launch browser in full screen mode.
2. Scroll using js, and then use sroll into view or Actions chain.

**Code :-**

```
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000)")
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Company data']"))))
# now use the mentioned xpath.

company_data_country_name` = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Company data']/../following-sibling::div/descendant::b[text()='Country']/../following-sibling::div")))
print(company_data_country_name.text)
```

Comment: Can you share page URL ?

Comment: You need to scroll first, to let selenium know where is the web element. `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'block__col') and contains(text(),'Country')]"))`

Comment: or probably you will have to change the locators `//div[contains(@class,'block__col')]/b[text()='Country']` use this as well

Comment: @LdM : I have tried to improve your code in try block, please use the updated 2 code and let me know for any issue.

Comment: When I open this https://www.scamadviser.com/check-website/github.com?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=pmd_eKyvx5ZPzsxwoOE7P.D8d6iXnBz3ORoD4mzpoAK.6Cg-1630663225-0-gqNtZGzNAeWjcnBszRH9 I see there are 13 time country is present so, `//b[text()='Country']/../following-sibling::div` will return the first web element if you use driver.find_element, or if driver.find_elements it should return all of them.

Comment: Thank you for having a look at that, cruisepandey. Let's say that I'd be interested in country from Server (ISP country) and from Company data: would it be ok to use the like of code you suggested in your previous comment above?

Comment: Yes we need to locate them uniquely, let me have a look once again, so basically two country one is from `Server (ISP country)` and `Company data` Am I right ?

Comment: Can you try updated 3 section above and let me know if that works ?

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help, @cruisepandey. Yes, it works. I will try by myself to make the df update working.

Comment: @LdM : Sure, you are welcome to create new tickets as and when requires.